# Set string-format to no commata on DataGridNumericUpDownColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting, mahapps.metro

I use the design-framework mahapps.metro for a datagridnumericupdowncolumn: https://mahapps.com/controls/datagrid.html

There is the example with stringformat=C. But I need D instead for only numbers with no commata: [string formats defined by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

```
<Controls:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Binding="{Binding DECIMAL_BINDING_VALUE}" StringFormat="D" Minimum="1" HideUpDownButtons="True"/>
```

Default value for the binded variable DECIMAL_BINDING_VALUE is 12345. If i open the window Visual Studio throws the exception:
**System.FormatException: "Format is invalid".** If i use String.Format=C I get no errors....

How can i define a correct StringFormat for no commata with the DatagridNumericUpDownColumn in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Controls:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Binding="{Binding DECIMAL_BINDING_VALUE, StringFormat='\{0:D\}'}" Minimum="1" HideUpDownButtons="True"/>
```

With the `StringFormat` inside the `Binding`.

This is how its done in the [BindingBase.StringFormat Property docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Damn... When i click into the cell the output responses to _System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'StringFormat' converter failed to convert value '0' (type 'Decimal'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=DECIMAL_BINDING_VALUE; DataItem='TBL_MYSPCLTABLE' (HashCode=41757008); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'CellContent' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Format is invalid._